# sitemap errors, using php to create it

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap for google, and I'm using php w\ a .htaccess file. I got the htaccess file to work just fine, it's my formatting in the php. Google gives me this error: 
Errors
Unsupported file format
Your Sitemap does not appear to be in a supported format. Please ensure it meets our Sitemap guidelines and resubmit.

I can't figure it out to save my life. When viewed locally it looks like it's working just fine. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$pictureCount = file_get_contents('http://dlolpics.com/funnyPicsHigh.html');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">';



set_time_limit(0); 
for($i = 1;$i <= $pictureCount;$i++){

if($i > 0 && $i < 2001){
    $directory_to_use = 1;

}elseif($i > 2000 && $i < 4001){
    $directory_to_use = 2;

}elseif($i > 4000 && $i < 6001){
    $directory_to_use = 3;

}elseif($i > 6000 && $i < 8001){
    $directory_to_use = 4;

}elseif($i > 8000 && $i < 10001){
    $directory_to_use = 5;

}elseif($i > 10000 && $i < 12001){
    $directory_to_use = 6;

}elseif($i > 12000 && $i < 14001){
    $directory_to_use = 7;

}elseif($i > 14000 && $i < 16001){
    $directory_to_use = 8;

}elseif($i > 16000 && $i < 18001){
    $directory_to_use = 9;

}elseif($i > 18000 && $i < 20001){
    $directory_to_use = 10;

}elseif($i > 20000 && $i < 22001){
    $directory_to_use = 11;

}
echo '<url>
<loc>http://www.dlolpics.com/?p='.$i.'</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://www.dlolpics.com/images/'.$directory_to_use.'/'.$i.'.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>';
usleep(290); 
}

echo '</urlset>';

?>
```

Comment: I don't think there should be a space in `<image:   loc>`

Comment: Ok I deleted it. Google is testing it right now, I'll let you know how it goes when it finishes. (also the space in the code above looks way bigger than what it really is in my php file. I have 1 space in my php code, but the code snippet above makes it look like it has 4+)

Comment: Nope I still get the same error. Unsupported format.

Comment: `echo '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`  sitemap.xml (or any other xml) should not start with an empty space or new line symbol before the `<?xml`!!!

Comment: Oh gosh, that is embarrassing. I hope that's the problem :o. Testing it now.

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems as if `<loc>` should be inside of every `<url>` tag as well... http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636

Comment: I think you are right @nachito, but I don't have a main url, I just have a image url. Should I just have both urls the same?       the code messed up when I posted it in the comment box, look at the main question to see what I mean

Comment: @Travis look at the standard and required elements http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: It should be the URL of the page that the image is located on. If it doesn't come from a page then I don't see the harm in having it be the image location.

Comment: Oh ok. Hmm gotta rethink this. I was going to have a separate sitemap that had where the images fell onto, because I have 10k+ urls. And I'm only allowed 50k urls per sitemap. Hmm. And I have two different pages that show the images, so between those it's a total of 30k urls. Doesn't leave me much room for more.

Comment: Ok so I added it to have <loc> and now I get this error: Errors
Parsing error
We were unable to read your Sitemap. It may contain an entry we are unable to recognize. Please validate your Sitemap before resubmitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pictureCount = file_get_contents('http://dlolpics.com/funnyPicsHigh.html');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n"
   . '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" ' . "\n"
   . '        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">' . "\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $pictureCount; $i++) {
    $dir = floor($i / 2000) + 1;
    $url = "http://www.dlolpics.com/images/$dir/" . ($i + 1) . '.jpg';
    echo '<url>'
       . '<loc>' . htmlentities($url) . '</loc>'
       . '<image:image><image:loc>' . htmlentities($url) . '</image:loc></image:image>'
       . "</url>\n";
}
echo '</urlset>';
```